# Multiple models into a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've seen this question asked on here, but it seems to be different than my situation.  I may be wrong about that but we will see.

Right now I am creating a blog type website in MVC3 (C#) and I can currently create, edit, delete etc a blog just fine and everything works.  I am using Code First EF, so I don't know how much that matters.

I have a BlogPost model as follows:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and a Topic model (each blog post can have multiple topics)

```
public class Topic
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    // navigation back to parent
    public BlogPost Post { get; set; }
}
```

Then there is my DbContext inherited model with all of my models in it:

```
public class MyModel : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogPost> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AdminComment> AdminComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bug> Bugs { get; set; }
}
```

Currently the BlogController is using the default scaffolding for create/edit/delete/details

```
private MyModel db = new MyModel();

//
// GET: /Admin/Blog/

public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Posts.ToList());
}
```

What can I do to pass in the other model as well so say on this list, it will show all topics associated with the posts, and also add in a create for adding topics to a post you are currently creating?

Comment: If you need to have topics as part of a post why don't you make them _part_ of the viewmodel for posts?

Comment: That would go against the conventions of relational data would it not?  Each post can have multiple topics, which means it needs to be its own table.  I am new to MVC3 and Code First EF, so if I am missing something, let me know.

Comment: Relational data? That's for databases, not ViewModels. And where in your post do you mention EF?

Comment: "I am using Code First EF", I thought the goal of EF was to attempt to mimic a real DB?  I don't see the point in creating a non-relational DB in EF, only to have to convert it later on..?

Comment: EF is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It is supposed to make the structure of the database _irrelevant_ to your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outer object that has the properties you want your view to be able to see, and use the new object as your model. You have pretty much already done this. Just change your controller to this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db);
}
```

Now the view has access to everything.

Comment: Okay so I changed the first line in my view from model IEnumerable<MvcBense.Models.MyModel> to model MvcBense.Models.MyModel to account for this, but could you point me in the right direction for how to deal with data on the .cshtml this way?  I currently have a foreach (var item in Model), but that won't work, and item.Title etc obviously are off now?

Comment: MyModel has a Posts property, so you access it with `foreach (var item in Model.Posts)`. MyModel is an object, and you are accessing the object passed into your view through the `View(db)` statement. From the view in the .cshtml file, the data you passed in is stored in the `Model` variable. Make sense?

Comment: Perfect sense :) You've been a big help, and one last question to throw me on my way. I'm grabbing each post like you said, so foreach (var post in Model.Posts) and I successfully grab title, date etc etc.  Now inside there I want another select to grab every topic that exists with that posts id... this all makes sense in my head but I don't know how to translate it to a razor page.  Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I just kind of figured it out... @foreach (var topic in Model.Topics) { if (post.id == topic.PostId) { <text>@topic.Name,</text> } } is that normal? :)

Comment: And now obviously figured out that isn't ideal at all or correct... should be 3 tables.. blogPost/BlogTopics/Topics, where BlogTopics holds postId/topicId... sorry if I am talking to myself at this point :)

Comment: You are on the right track. The goal is to make the object you pass to your view (the *model*) have everything you need to render the page correctly (the *view*). The *controller* loads up the model and passes it to the view.